# Cannot find resource dictionary in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm in the process of building a WPF application and ran into an error when trying to reference a resource dictionary. Inside my WPF application project I have a folder called "Styles" to contain all the xaml style templates for my app:

[image: VS2010 Solution Explorer]

In my app.xaml file I have this:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/MetroTheme.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

However, when I hover over the source property I get an error saying "An error occurred while finding the resource dictionary "Styles/MetroTheme.xaml". I can see the xaml file inside the folder both in Visual Studio and in the file system.

I have also tried "/Styles/MetroTheme.xaml" and a pack uri for the source property, both with no success. Any idea why I'm getting this file not found error?

Comment: What's the build action set to on MetroTheme.xaml? set it to page

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure that the build action for MetroTheme.xaml is set to Page.

[image]

Comment: This appears to have taken care of the error. Thank you for the assistance!

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue, but setting ***Build Action = Page*** did not solve for me. Turned out I needed to use the [Pack URI Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx). So,

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Styles/MetroTheme.xaml"/>
```

**EDIT**

Turns out the above will eliminate build error but still results in runtime error. I needed to include full assembly specification for complete resolution (even though all files are in same assembly):

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WpfApplication10;component/Styles/MetroTheme.xaml"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes closing Visual Studio and open it again solves this problem.

Comment: As silly/simple as this might sound... I tried everything and THEN this. Turns out this is all I needed to do. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm it because of some strange behavior on relative uri.
For example:

> /SubProjectDir/WhatThingDir/YourResource.xaml
>
> ```
> <ResourceDictionary>
>    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TheBrush" Color="Black" />
> </ResourceDictionary>
> ```

> /SubProjectDir/AnotherDir/YourControl.xaml
>
> ```
> ...
> <ResourceDictionary>
>     <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
>         <ResourceDictionary Source="/WhatThingDir/YourResource.xaml" />
>     </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
> </ResourceDictionary>
> ...
> ```

> /MainExecution/MainWindow.xaml
>
> ```
> ...
> <sub:YourControl />
> ...
> ```

It looks work well in designer. But when you run it, will throw cannot find resource execption.

Because `/WhatThingDir/YourResource.xaml` means "Find the related resource from **current root path**", but now the `MainWindow` constructed `YourControl`, so the **current root  path** is start under `MainExecution`. Then, it try to find the resource path `/WhatThingDir/YourResource.xaml` in `MainExecution`. That's must fail!

But if you write this, it will works be fine:

> /SubProjectDir/AnotherDir/YourControl.xaml
>
> ```
> ...
> <ResourceDictionary>
>     <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
>         <ResourceDictionary Source="../WhatThingDir/YourResource.xaml" />
> <!--                           Here ^^^ Here                          -->
>     </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
> </ResourceDictionary>
> ...
> ```

That's will seek the resource in `/SubProjectDir/AnotherDir/../WhatThingDir/YourResource.xaml` => `/SubProjectDir/WhatThingDir/YourResource.xaml`.
It's ok!

Answer (score -1):

Change the target .net version to an older one in the project properties and then reset to the previous version.