# WPF Resources - the property can have only one child element if it uses an explicit collection tag

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, resourcedictionary

I am trying to add a resource dictionary to a user control as follows:

**User Control** View/AllOrdersView.xaml

[image: UserControl]

**Resource Dictionary** View/AllOrdersViewResources.xaml

[image: ResourceDictionary]

**Solution Explorer** Showing the UserControl and ResourceDictionary

[image: SolutionExplorer]

**Error Message**

> Cannot add element to property 'Resources', because the property can
>   have only one child element if it uses an explicit collection tag.

**Troubleshooting Steps**

- Ensure the build action of AllOrderViewResource.xaml is "page" as suggested in this question: [Cannot find resource dictionary in WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053393/cannot-find-resource-dictionary-in-wpf-application)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your XAML is wrong. This is the right way to merge ResourceDictionaries:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
       <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
           <ResourceDictionary Source="AllOrdersViewResources.xaml"/>
       </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

       <!-- More resources here -->
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```